# How to mount azure file share on windows azure virtual machine?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-sdk-.net

I want to do some automation in my project .When user will select any storage account from dropdown i am showing attached File Share. Now I want if user will select any File Share and any azure virtual machine then selected File Share should be mounted on virtual machine. So any Azure .Net SDK, Fluent API or Powershell script which will support this kind automation.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if you have any responses.

Comment: @Charles Xu Thank you for the ans can you provide me full code of implementation IVirtualMachineRunCommandsOperations .

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, here are two workarounds. One is that you can use the [`IVirtualMachineRunCommandsOperations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.fluent.ivirtualmachineruncommandsoperations?view=azure-dotnet) Interface to execute the PowerShell script which mounts the Azure File Share to the Windows VM. Another is that you can also use the [`IVirtualMachineExtensionsOperations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.fluent.ivirtualmachineextensionsoperations?view=azure-dotnet) Interface to execute the PowerShell script. You can get more details about the PowerShell script that mount the Azure File Share to the Windows VM [here](https://charbelnemnom.com/how-to-mount-and-persist-an-azure-file-share-with-windows-azurefiles-azurefilesync/).